# HP Laptop battery issues

Tags: laptop, battery

My HP DV6 1106ax laptop with Windows 7 64-bit is about two years old. The battery died recently - it wouldn't charge and would turn off as soon as I unplugged it from the power.

I bought a new battery the other day which worked perfectly on the first charge. When I first put it in, it read about 80%; I charged it to 100% then unplugged it and ran it flat.

I then plugged it in and left it for a while. When I turned it on it said the battery has 43% and doesn't get any higher than that. If I unplug it from the power the laptop dies.

Does anyone have any advice? I find it strange that it charged up and ran off the battery the first time I put it in but now it won't work. I've tried reinserting the battery to make sure it's sitting right and all seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's a problem with the on-board charging circuitry.  Either that or simply a bad battery contact.

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering that now. Guess there isn't a whole lot I can do about it. Seems strange that it charged up that one time though.

Comment: The one successful charge would suggest a bad battery contact.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some problem with the power supply. I suggest to measure the voltage and amperage of the power supply and if its different than on the label of the charger you should replace it and the new battery too i guess. You can also try to download [HP Battery Check](http://h20239.www2.hp.com/techcenter/battery/battery_ts.htm) and change the options to advanced diagnostics to see what it says.

Comment: The voltage and amperage ok. The only thing that has changed between this battery and the last is this one is double the capacity.

Answer (score 0):

What type of battery? Li-Ion batteries can be *damaged* by running them completely down. The old NiCad batteries that was the correct thing to do. Modern ones, it's the opposite. Annoying but true.

Comment: Li-Ion yeah I only run it down to just under 10% before I plugged it back in.

Comment: The laptop should shut down before the battery is damaged.